# Problema con procesos asincronos

Tags: java, android

estoy haciendo unos ejercicios con el tema de procesos asíncronos y al momento de utilizando un ciclo for actualice un textview surge el siguiente problema les adjunto mi codigo y el error que figura en el logcat

Adjunto el codigo donde se produce el error

```
public class ProcesoB extends Thread
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        super.run();

        for (int i = 0 ; i <= 10 ; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                ProcesoUNO.TextAsincrono2.setText("Durmiendo en el paso numero " + i);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Codigo de la activity principal donde activo el Thread

```
if (view.getId() == Demorar15segundosHiloSecundario.getId())
        {
            ProcesoA A1 = new ProcesoA();
            new Thread(A1).start();


            ProcesoB A2 = new ProcesoB();
            new Thread(A2).start();
        }
```

Error en LogCat

```
Process: com.example.procesosasincronos, PID: 7784
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:7396)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:22013)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:22013)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:22013)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:22013)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:22013)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:22013)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:22013)
        at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:8573)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5423)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5279)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5236)
        at com.example.procesosasincronos.ProcesosEnSegundoPlano.ProcesoB.run(ProcesoB.java:24)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, me temo que adjuntar imagenes en lugar de compartir el código no nos ayuda en nada. Por favor si eres tan amable edita tu pregunta con el codigo en lugar de las fotos :)

Comment: El problema es porque intentas modificar la vista desde un hilo que no es el principal, para eso mira esta pregunta, es muy sencillo solucionarlo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi

Comment: Gracias por ese link @PabloSimonDiEstefano intente implementar este codigo " runOnUiThread(new Runnable() " pero es marcado como error , Que puede ser?

Answer (score 0):

Esto pasa porque estás intentando modificar vistas del hilo principal (Interfaz de usuario) desde un proceso en "segundo plano", el mismo error lo dice en la sigueinte línea:

```
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Tienes que crear un proceso llamado runOnUiThread

Por lo que tendrías algo como

```
((MainActivity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ProcesoUNO.TextAsincrono2.setText("Durmiendo en el paso numero " + i);
    }
});
```

Comment: Disculpa , ese codigo lo inserto en la activity ?

Comment: No, debes insertarlo en donde está el hilo

Comment: Añadelo al bloque 'finally{}'